# Change folder name on Github

Tags: github

Regrettably I uploaded a folder named 3d Modeller to GitHub. I want to change the name to Modeller as if I upload separate files they get stored in an extra 3d%20Modeller/, whereas bulk uploads get stored in 3d Modeller/ ... hence the regrets! Answers I found here are beyond me. Anyone know a solution for a simpleton?

Edit:

Actually I was looking for a gui solution - hence for simpleton - that might have arrived within the last year or two.  If there's a gui then it seems probable that it will become as comprehensive as its old time counterpart. Seems not so, so have to accept as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

```
git mv "3d Modeller" Modeller
git commit -m "
git push
```

That's it.